# Access an object created in another class

Tags: java, spring-mvc, controller, request-mapping

I have a main class in which i am creating object of a class which connects to the database.  How can i use this object in  a controller class ?

```
public class A {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        connectToDb x=new connectToDb();  // makes a connection to database


    }
```

now i want to use this object in spring controller class which has a method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/whatever/, method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public @ResponseBody Object getFilteredLogs() {
            ....

        }
```

so how can i use that object in this controller class ?

Comment: read [How to Ask a Good Question](/help/how-to-ask) and provide an [mcve]

Comment: When I try and compile your example it just says: `cannot find symbol: class connecttoDB`

Comment: this is not the whole code. I have a connecttoDB class which makes the connection. The whole code is very huge.

Comment: Is there a way i can access the object created in main class in some other class ?

Comment: See my first comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is a Spring application, you should consider autowirering. If the class connecttoDB is annotated with @Service or @Repository you can put

```
@Inject connecttoDB;
```

In your controller, ant Spring will create a connecttoDB singleton and inject it.

I would also look at spring Data, but that is not necessary to solve your current problem.